# SpringSecurityCore grails plugin breaks my (previously working) multipart upload form

Tags: grails, file-upload, spring-security

Well not the form exactly - but the action that the form submits to.

Whats is happening is that SpringSecurity is wrapping the request in its own request context that obviously has a lot of security happening in it. My action that catches the POST request from the form breaks on this line:

```
def f = request.getFile('myFile')
```

with the error message:

```
No signature of method: org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.getFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [myFile]
```

Anyone know how to get at the actual file from the request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your form a proper file upload form? It needs the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute set. If you're using `<g:form>` you can switch to `<g:uploadForm>` which adds that for you.

Comment: Edit: Never mind, my problem seems to be related to JMeter not setting correct mimetype for file. I just ran into the exact same thing.  As Dave said, the upload is configured properly and was working, then when we enabled Spring Security it breaks.  Based on the error message I am thinking that the Spring Security RequestWrapper is being used instead of the Multipart wrapper that Grails would normally automatically use.

Answer (score 1):

Just let me know if you are using  or  to submit your form.
If possible please add your complete Form Code